# Metric tensors. Have I got the correct understanding?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, tensors

My course is covering metric tensors in a slap-dash way, so I want to ensure I have understood correctly how they are described.

I hope you can confirm this!

So, I believe that a metric tensor is a $(0,2)$ tensor, $g$, satisfying a certain property. By a $(0,2)$ tensor I mean that it is a map $g : T_pM\times T_pM \mapsto \mathbb{R}$. Where $M$ is some smooth manifold, and $p\in M$.

Now the condition for $g$ to be called a metric tensor is that it must be a inner product.

Now in co-ordinate form we may write $g(X,Y) = X^iY^jg_{ij}$. And so am I right in thinking that g is a metric tensor iff $g_{ii} > 0$ for each $i$?

I.e we could choose any real values $g_{ij}$ and so long as $g_{ii} >0$ for each $i$, then we would have a $(0,2)$ tensor?

I hope you can clarify things for me!

Comment: There are also (0,2) tensors that are anti-symmetric or totally unsymmetric. What you need is that the matrix formed by the $g_{ij}$ is (symmetric) positive definite, $g_{ii}>0$ is only a part of that.

Comment: The metric tensor is (1) symmetric, $g(X,Y)=g(Y,X)$, and (2) positive definite, $g(X,X)>0$ if $X\neq 0$. In coordinates, (1) says $g_{ij}=g_{ji}$, while (2) is more than $g_{ii} >0$. There are 2 ways (at least) to say it. 1st: if you diagonalize $g$, then $g_{ii}>0.$ 2nd: each subdeterminant of $g$ is positive. In fact, its enough to check for the $n$ nested subdeterminants, obtained by restricting $g_{ij}$ to the range $1\leq i,j\leq k$,  $k=1,2,\ldots, n$.

Answer (score 0):

You must also require $g_{ij}=g_{ji}:$ inner products are symmetric. You need bilinearity as well, but let's assume that's what you meant by $g$ being a "map" on $T_p M\times T_p M$.

Now, this is fine as far as it goes, but is actually nothing more or less than the definition of an inner product on a real vector space. What really becomes interesting is when you put a metric on $TM$, rather than just $T_p M$, which is a smoothly varying family of inner products as described above. This is called a (metric) tensor *field*, and the possibility of putting one on every smooth manifold is the real beginning of Riemannian geometry.

Comment: Oh, yes I meant to include symmetry. Thank you for confirming!